# How to dynamically change attribute value depending on the selected swatch or size?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, attributes, swatches

I have a table in which I want to display product attribute data there, depending on the selected size or swatch.

[image]

So that the value of the attributes in the table changes dynamically

How to dynamically retrieve this data when clicked?